# Background color angular

Tags: html, css, angular, scss, angular-7

Como faço, em angular 7, uma background-color do body diferente da página que estou exibindo?

Exemplo:

- Página login: background verde
- Página home: background azul

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de qualquer um dos seus componentes. Por exemplo:

```js
 export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
       constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef){

       }
       ngAfterViewInit(){
         this.elementRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = 'yourColor';
      }
   }
```